# Ftp works locally but not on published app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have communication with FTP server like this:

```
try
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    Debug.Log("Making request");
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(u);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPW);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    streamReader.Close();

    list = lines.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

    return list;
}catch(Exception ex) { Debug.Log(ex.ToString()); throw new ARException(ex.ToString()); }
```

Now when i run it locally it works but when i publish that app to my webserver it returns me error `System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server`

Now what i think it may be is that for some reason `SSL` is blocking connection but i do not know what to do or how to fix it.

Comment: your server maybe close the ftp port for security reason.

Comment: try to connect with command line ftp, and see if the settings are correct - if you connect or not with command line ftp

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting the exception for the InnerException property. This may give some additional info. Could be a firewall that is blocking the port, could be an FTP server which enforces security, ... Do you have control over the server to check its configuration and firewall or can you reach out to the administrator to get proper connection parameters? Otherwise you can only use some FTP client which supports multiple protocols and try to find out the correct parameters. If you use something like FileZilla client, the client may give you also some more hints.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on server side where prot was blocked by them.